# REST API - non-static (changing) resource for single url - how to design?

Tags: rest, api-design

Imagine I have an API for a school. One of the resources is `Department`, which has various resources on it, such as a collection of `Professors`, and a "Head Professor".

Department looks like this:

```
{
    "_links": {
                  "self": "http://myapi.com/department/math"
    }
    "name": "Math Department",
    "headProfessor": {
                "_links": {
                              "self": "http://myapi.com/professor/id/2",
                              "headProfessor": "http://myapi.com/headprofessor/department/math"
                },
                "name": "George Patton",
                "id": "2"
    }
    "professors": {
        "_links": {
                      "self": "http://myapi.com/professors/department/math"
        },
        "_collectionData": [
            {
                "_links": {
                      "self": "http://myapi.com/professor/id/1"
                },
                "name": "John Doe",
                "id": "1"
            },
            {
                "_links": {
                      "self": "http://myapi.com/professor/id/2"
                },
                "name": "George Patton",
                "id": "2"
            },
            {
                "_links": {
                      "self": "http://myapi.com/professor/id/3"
                },
                "name": "Paul Simon",
                "id": "3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My question is regarding "headProfessor" and the links. What is the canonical link for the "head professor"? Is it `http://myapi.com/professor/id/1` or is it `http://myapi.com/headprofessor/department/math`? Should I have both in there? Or is only one necessary? Is there a better way to represent the "head" or the "top" of something, basically a url whose resource could change because it represents a relationship and not a static resource?

**NOTE**

Yes, I do prefer the resource designator first in the url as it gives the resource designator the same location in every url. But my question is not about that. That's just a matter of taste and style.

Comment: GET on /departments/{deptId}/professors cannot be the same as GET professors/{professorId}/departments REST doesnt specify naming it that way, because the first means give me all professors from depart with id deptId, second means give me all departments where professor of profId is teaching. It could be very well your style but definitely not RESTful URIs.

Answer (score 1):

First of all Department has professors and not vice-versa so your APIs should be designed like this

```
http://myapi.com/departments   -> GET all departments
http://myapi.com/departments/{departmentId}/professors ---> POST to add a professor to a department , body of POST has the rank of professor has HOD, or staff
http://myapi.com/departments/{departmentId}/professors ---> GET should get all professors of that department
http://myapi.com/departments/{departmentId}/professors?rank=hod ---> Should give you the HOD 
http://myapi.com/departments/{departmentId}/professors/{professorId} ---> PUT to change rank of Professor
http://myapi.com/departments/{departmentId}/professors/{professorId} ---> DELETE to remove professor from Department if he retires or moves to another college,etc.
```

Comment: The only difference in your API endpoints is the location of the resource designator, i.e. you put the resource designator last (departments/professors), whereas I prefer it first, so that the resource designator is always in the same place (first). Otherwise, you did the same that I did. My question is more about the response and how the endpoints should be represented.

Comment: There are two parts to this , first it is not about preference but relationship,  irrespective of how much we may prefer professors belong to departments and not vice-versa.
Second part is the question you asked has been addressed, that you shouldnt have dedicated resource for headprofessor but should do a query param as I pointed out in the 3rd URI.Please go through all the URI's I listed. How to POST a professor as a Head Of Department , how to GET the hod, how to edit a professor from hod to another professor being hod, all have been listed.

Comment: The relationship can be represented either way "professors/departments" or "departments/professors", as long as the API is consistent. I prefer the resource designator to come first.

Comment: I don't think it necessarily should be a query param? Why do you think it should be? It's not a query...it's an actual resource.

Comment: Reply to the first question
GET on /departments/{deptId}/professors 
cannot be the same as GET professors/{professorId}/departments 
REST doesnt specify naming it that way, because the first means give me all professors from depart with id deptId, second means give me all departments wher professor of ProfId is teaching.

Comment: 2nd point - It is  a query param when you GET it, coz you want to query from the many profesors of the dept who is the HOD, but when you POST you just give the professor position in the body as a hod or staff, also in PUT you just modify /professors/{proffersorId} with the position in the body, that is the way it can be GET,POST and PUT while the role changes to different professors.